# Get array value with unknown key

Tags: php, arrays

I have an multidimensional array that follows certain pattern but 'x' element is always different?

This is a pattern:

```
$category['children'][x]['alias']
```

How to bypass 'x' and get that values?

Comment: Get what value?  Are there many different x's?

Comment: Do you want the 'alias' value for all the x's or just a specific one?

Comment: `foreach($category['children'] as $x) { foreach($x as $alias) { //code here using $alias; }}`? Loops through each `x` to get its values? Not sure the full context or usage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also extract all of the `alias` columns if that is the only one you are concerned with:

```
$aliases = array_column($category['children'], 'alias');
```

If you just want the first one:

```
$alias = reset($category['children'])['alias'];
```

Comment: I like your answer, however, using reset makes an assumption that isn't necessarily true.  It will only work if the first element of $category['children'] is an array with an 'alias' element.  We don't know whether that is true given the question.  Also array_column was introduced in php 5.5, so it's relatively new.

Comment: Yes we must assume when the question doesn't stipulate much, but as for 5.5, it's 4 years old and support ended 1 year ago.

Comment: Good point on 5.5. Personally, I think your answer is the best one provided, and works even if the array won't work with the reset() based solution.

Comment: Sorry for not providing enough information about what I wanted, yet you still managed to figure it out, Thanks, your post answers my question.

Answer (score 2):

```
$children = $category['children'];
$x        = array_pop($children);
$theValue = $children['alias'];
```

This assumes a few things, you have not provided in your question.

Comment: Works, but only if every element in $category['children'] is an array with an 'aiias' key in it.  We don't know from the question unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all keys of an array using `array_keys`

```
$current = array_keys($category['children']);

$value = $category["children"][$current[0]]["alias"];
```

This code will get the value of index `alias` in the first item in the sub array "children".

Comment: You have the same flaw as several other solutions, in that this doesn't work if the first element of the $category['children'] array, doesn't have an 'alias' key member.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the 'alias' values for all x's, then you can just loop through them:

```
$alias = new array();
foreach($category['children'] as $x) {
  $alias[] = $x['alias'];
}
```